# Where is the source code of libgazebo_ros plugins?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am currently using the libgazebo_ros_projector plugin and while using it in urdf it calls the binary ".so" file as follows:

```
<plugin name="projector_test_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_projector.so">
```

Where can I find the source code of it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21162/where-is-the-source-code-of-libgazebo_ros-plugins?/) by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5170/hbaqueiro/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here it is: https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_projector.cpp

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5170/hbaqueiro/) on 2018-11-30**:
Thanks! I discovered just recently that the source codes don't have the "lib" prefix, that's why I couldn't find anything :)